# TextView setAllCaps will be ignored when editable or selectable

Tags: android, textview

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAllCaps(boolean)) of the Android TextView's method `setAllCaps(boolean)` says that

> this setting will be ignored if this field is editable or selectable.

I was just wondering what the reason behind this could be.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setAllCaps(boolean)` can also be used to `EditText` (although it's not mentioned in the documentation or I could not find it) which is editable and of course it will be ignored there.  
So maybe the documentation for TextView is just generalized for all the classes that use this method.  
Also `TextView` had an `android:editable` property that now is deprecated and if the atribute `android:textIsSelectable` is set to `true` I suppose makes the `android:textAllCaps` attribute ignored because selection is mainly needed to copy and paste, so you can't copy `OK` and paste `ok`  since the actual `text` property returns `ok`

Comment: Well, it's not just a generalized documentation. `setAllCaps` is actually ignored when I set `android:textIsSelectable="true"` in the XML.

Comment: That sounds reasonable but would also be a bit disappointing if that was the case.

Comment: In my case I need to use `setAllCaps` depending on a configuration. `android:textIsSelectable` withheld me from doing that. Imo it wouldn't be difficult to change `TextView` to make both usable at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you keep `android:textIsSelectable` and set the text of the `TextView` in uppercase? So you have both.

Comment: I have to decide whether the `TextView` should be uppercase during runtime.

Comment: So you keep textIsSelectable=true, setAllCaps=false and at runtime after you decide you set textView.setTex("text") or textView.setTex("TEXT")